# How to unnest/explode/flatten the comma separated value in a column in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, split, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

I am trying to generate a new row for each value in col2. As the value is in string format, I need to wrap it in double quotes before using any Redshift json function on it.

Input:

```
col1(int)       col2(varchar)
1               ab,cd,ef
2               gh
3               jk,lm,kn,ut,zx
```

Output:

```
col1(int)       col2(varchar)
1               ab
1               cd
1               ef
2               gh
3               jk
3               lm
3               kn
3               ut
3               zx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    with NS AS (
      select 1 as n union all
      select 2 union all
      select 3 union all
      select 4 union all
      select 5 union all
      select 6 union all
      select 7 union all
      select 8 union all
      select 9 union all
      select 10
    )
    select
      TRIM(SPLIT_PART(B.col2, ',', NS.n)) AS col2
    from NS
    inner join table B ON NS.n <= REGEXP_COUNT(B.col2, ',') + 1
```

Here, the NS (number sequence) is a CTE that returns a list of number from 1 to N, here we have to make sure that our max number is greater than the size of our maximum tags, so you can try adding more numbers to the list depending on your context.

Comment: This answer appears to be taken from [here](https://www.holistics.io/blog/splitting-array-string-into-rows-in-amazon-redshift-or-mysql/).