# Split a Column with Delimited Values and Compare Each Value

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, split, amazon-redshift

I have a column that contains multiple values in a delimited(comma-separated) format -

```
id | code
------------
1   11,19,21
2   55,87,33
3   3,11
4   11
```

I want to be able to compare to each value inside the 'code' column as below -

```
SELECT id FROM myTbl WHERE code = '11'
```

This should return -

```
1
3
4
```

I've tried the solution below but it does not work for all cases -

```
SELECT id FROM myTbl WHERE POSITION('11' IN code) <> 0
```

This will work with a 2 digit number like '11' as it will return a value that is <> 0 if it finds a match. But it will fail when searching for say '3' because rows with 'id' 2 and 3 both will be returned.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_POSITION.html) is link that talks about the POSITION function in REDSHIFT.

Any other approach that will solve this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma delimited values in a single column to begin with.

Comment: This happened because the table is rolledup/aggregated to a level and we didn't want to lose information from a column

Comment: @sandunes90 . . . You have taken the wrong approach to aggregating your data.

Comment: Split_part would fit for this use case. Refer this query : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262231/how-to-unnest-explode-flatten-the-comma-separated-value-in-a-column-in-amazon-re

Answer (score 0):

you can get the count of this string

```
SELECT id FROM myTbl WHERE regexp_count(user_action, '[11]') > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`split_part()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) function

```
SELECT distinct id 
  FROM myTbl 
 WHERE '11' in ( split_part( code||',' , ',', 1 ), 
                 split_part( code||',' , ',', 2 ), 
                 split_part( code||',' , ',', 3 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use `regexp_substr()` as follow.

```
select tb .id from myTbl tb where '11' in (
    select regexp_substr( (select code from myTbl where id=tb.id),'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) from dual
    connect by regexp_substr((select code from myTbl where id=tb.id) , '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) is not null);
```

just try this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very, very bad data model.  You should be storing this information in a junction/association table, with one row per value.

But, if you have no choice, you can use `like`:

```
SELECT id
FROM myTbl
WHERE ',' || code || ',' LIKE '%,11,%';
```