# explode column with comma separated string in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below dataset

```
+----+-----------+
|col1|       col2|
+----+-----------+
|   1|val1, val2 |
|   2|val3, val4 |
+----+-----------+
```

Consider all values as String
Now i want to convert it into below dataset

```
+----+-----------+
|col1|       col2|
+----+-----------+
|   1|val1       |
|   1|val2       |
|   2|val3       |
|   2|val4       |
+----+-----------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How can we write the same for redshift.
We need to create a udf for it.
Can someone help me to create the udf

Comment: @Etisha check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58766516/2890093).

Answer (score 8):

Use [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#split(str:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:String,limit:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to parse comma-separated values as an array, then [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#explode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to rearrange array elements into separate rows.

```
df.withColumn("col2", explode(split($"col2", ","))).show
```

Comment: I am using SQL editor and this worked for me 
`SELECT explode(split(col1, ",")) FROM table`